# Расположение элементов html в правой стороне экрана

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, figma

Я написал меню для своего сайта, и получилось так, что в правой части экрана образовалось пустое место. Я вставил туда изображение типа "здесь может быть ваша реклама" и решил ниже поставить изображения, однако после того как я вставил вторую картинку, все картинки стали размером с Юпитер, и плевать они хотели на всё что я делал.

```css
.rightside {
  float: right;
}

.adplace {
  height: 70%;
  width: 70%;
}
```

```html
<div class="rightside">
  <img src="img/youad.jpg" class="adplace" alt="Место для рекламы">
  <img src="img/col/bug.jpg" class="colphoto" alt="картошка">
  <img src="img/col/ara.jpg" class="colphoto" alt="укроп">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Почитай про СSS Flexbox [Удобная штука](https://tproger.ru/translations/how-css-flexbox-works/)!